# Why is multithreading time not equal to individual processing time with gunicorn?

Tags: multithreading, performance, time, gunicorn

I use gunicorn to allow my Flask rest API to process multiple requests at the same time. I have 5 workers in my gunicorn config (2 x $(NUM_CORES) + 1). I measured the response time and here are my results :

- The response time for 1 request is 20s.
- If I send 5 requests at the same time, the response time for each request is 55s.
- If I send 6 requests at the same time, the response time for the first 5 requests is 55s and the response time for the 6th request is 75s ( = 55 + 20 )

I don't understand why 5 requests at the same time takes 55s. I expected a 20 seconds response time, as for 1 request, thinking it would process the 5 requests in parallel at the same time.

55 seconds is almost 3 times more than 20 seconds, my individual processing time.

I don't know much about multithreading. Can someone explain me why the response time for parallel tasks is that longer than individual processing time ?

Thanks

Comment: How would I reproduce your results?  It depends what the requests are doing.  It depends how they synchronize and what shared resources they are contending for.  The specific details matter -- they make all the difference, in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I had these results is because 5 workers was too much in my case.
I chose 5 because of gunicorn recommendation [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html)

> Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers
> to start off with. While not overly scientific, the formula is based
> on the assumption that for a given core, one worker will be reading or
> writing from the socket while the other worker is processing a
> request.

In my case all, the requests I was sending at the same time were all to process parameters. Therefore I changed the workers number to 2 and I have now results that make sense to me.

- The response time for 1 request is 20s.
- If I send 2 requests at the same time, the response time for each request is 20s.
- If I send 3 requests at the same time, the response time for the first 2 requests
  is 20s and the response time for the 3rd request is 40s.